# Export a string to csv

Tags: c#, csv

I'm new to exporting to csv. I have a string that is generated from a gridview
(str = coups.Cells[0].Text + " -- " + coups.Cells[1].Text).
I would like to know how to export this to a csv file.

How do i generate headers in the csv file and then match them up.

I'm new to exporting to csv.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with this?

```
TextWriter x = File.OpenWrite ("my.csv", ....);

x.WriteLine("Column1,Column2"); // header
x.WriteLine(coups.Cells[0].Text + "," + coups.Cells[1].Text);
```

The column delimiter is a comma.  This is sufficient:

```
Column1,Column2
data,data2
data,data2
```

They don't have to line up visually like this:.

```
Column1,    Column2
data,       data2
data,       data2
```

Edit:  In the United States, Comma means `,` and semicolon means `;`.  You'll want to pick the delimiter that your software uses.

Comment: Be careful though. As I mentioned in my answer, if coups.Cells[0].Text or coups.Cells[1].Text can contain a comma, then you will need to surround them with quotes.

Comment: And if a quoted value contains a `"` quote, you have to escape the `"` as `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a method I wrote a while back that you can pass a string into and it formats it for CSV... just seperate each string by a ; and it will be in a seperate column.  Do a new line (hard return) to signify another row.  Sorry this in VB.NET

```
Private Function FormatStringForCsvFile(ByVal strCSV As String) As String
        Dim addDoubleQuotes As Boolean = False
        Dim strReturn As String = strCSV
        If strReturn IsNot Nothing AndAlso strReturn.Length > 0 Then
            'if the string contains any double quotes then we need to change those double quotes to 2x double quotes
            If strReturn.Contains("""") Then
                strReturn = strReturn.Replace("""", """""")
                addDoubleQuotes = True
            End If
            'if the string contains a comma, any spaces before or after, 
            'any 2x double quotes, or a new line then we need to enclose it in double quotes
            If strReturn.Contains(",") Or Char.IsWhiteSpace(strReturn(0)) _
                Or Char.IsWhiteSpace(strReturn(strReturn.Length - 1)) _
                Or addDoubleQuotes Or strReturn.Contains(vbCrLf) Then
                strReturn = """" & strReturn & """"
            End If
        End If

        Return strReturn

    End Function
```

This method is used to format the string which you want to seperate with the ; deliminator because your string which your seperating does not always conform to csv rules.  If there is a ; or " or hard return in your string.. well you need to enclose that in double quotes.. This will let the program which is rendering the csv that the ; " are all part of the string and not signifying a deliminator

Answer (score 0):

Csv is just list of string with ; between cells

String with ; you should have in quotes

Example

```
Language; Country
RU; Russia
EN; UK
"string with ; in ";I like StackOverFlow
```

Comment: Actually is it a comma, not a semi-colon (hance the C in CSV).

Comment: It's either a comma or a semi-colon depending on your regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues. So any string concatenation method will work. The only tricky part is that if a value contains a comma, then the entire value needs to be surrounded by quotes like this:

"Mouse, Mickey", Disney Land, USA

Answer (score 0):

`How do i generate headers in the csv file and then match them up.`

CSV Means `Comma Separated Value`, here each values is Separated with `,`. There is nothing special as headers. However, You can consider the First Row as a header.